# mup MongoDB Configuration Copy Failing

Tags: linux, meteor

Using mup, I'm running into a problem of being unable to copy the MongoDB configuration.

TaskList:

```
[example.com] - Installing Node.js
[example.com] - Installing Node.js: SUCCESS
[example.com] - Installing PhantomJS
[example.com] - Installing PhantomJS: SUCCESS
[example.com] - Setting up Environment
[example.com] - Setting up Environment: SUCCESS
[example.com] - Copying MongoDB configuration
[example.com] x Copying MongoDB configuration: FAILED
        Permission denied
```

mup.json:

```
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "example.com",
      "username": "collin"
    }
  ],
  "setupMongo": true,
  "setupNode": true,
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.40",
  "setupPhantom": true,
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true,
  "appName": "Example",
  "app": "/path/to/proper/location,
  "env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "http://example.com"
  },
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15
}
```

I have already adjusted `visudo` with `collin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`. No other errors have been showing up (to my knowledge).

Comment: This is mostly a permission issue, are you running a DO ubuntu based? just to be sure try changing username to "root" or "ubuntu" and try, if it works this is a permission error, btw i recommend you to use ssh

Comment: @Ethaan I am running a Digital Ocean remote server. I do not have immediate access to root, however I can get it. Are you suggesting that I poke around in the MongoDB configuration area and see if collin is having the permission error?